# How do I use Itertools to create all combinations of a range of Chrono dates?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to generate all combinations of a date range using [Rust itertools](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.8/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations) but it says that trait bounds were not satisfied.

```
extern crate chrono;
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;
use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let min = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2018, 10, 1);
    let max = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2018, 10, 14);
    let combinations = (min..=max).combinations(5);
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `combinations` found for type `std::ops::RangeInclusive<chrono::NaiveDate>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:46:36
   |
46 |     let combinations = (min..=max).combinations(5);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `combinations` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `std::ops::RangeInclusive<chrono::NaiveDate> : itertools::Itertools`
           `&std::ops::RangeInclusive<chrono::NaiveDate> : itertools::Itertools`
           `&mut std::ops::RangeInclusive<chrono::NaiveDate> : itertools::Itertools`
```

I would expect that `Itertools` were implemented for generic `RangeInclusive`. I am learning Rust so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that `chrono` doesn't implement `Iterator` for ranges of its date types.

Comment: I see, it's not that `itertools` are implemented for ranges, they are implemented for `Iterator` which is not always possible for a range (for example, `Range<f32>`) but it could be possible for `Range<NaiveDate>` but `chrono` doesn't implement it.

Comment: More info https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/152

Comment: What would be the result of such combination ?

Comment: It's an iterator over mathematical combinations, the subsets of the given size of elements of the iterator. I have no idea why you would need that for dates. On the other hand, simple ranges of dates would be quite useful for calendars.

Comment: @starblue Why would you need it for integers or any other type? :) In my case I'm working with dates and I could do integer combinations and add them to the min date, but I was wondering why it's not possible in this more straightforward way. The answers below helped. When `Step` gets stable and if `chrono` implements it, then it should become possible I think.

Answer (score 2):

Itertools, as the name suggests, works on *`Iterator`s*. It is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48321087/155423) to create an iterable range of a type from outside of the standard library in stable Rust (version 1.29).

Instead, we can create a custom iterator for a date range, based on [looping over dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41679239/155423)

```
extern crate chrono; // 0.4.6
extern crate itertools; // 0.7.8

use chrono::{Duration, NaiveDate};
use itertools::Itertools;
use std::mem;

struct DateRange(NaiveDate, NaiveDate);

impl Iterator for DateRange {
    type Item = NaiveDate;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.0 < self.1 {
            let next = self.0 + Duration::days(1);
            Some(mem::replace(&mut self.0, next))
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let min = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2018, 10, 1);
    let max = NaiveDate::from_ymd(2018, 10, 14);
    let combinations: Vec<_> = DateRange(min, max).combinations(5).collect();
    println!("{:?}", combinations)
}
```

- [Iterating over a range of generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48321087/155423)
- [Loop over date range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41679239/155423)

Comment: The formal orphan rule is in the coherence RFC 1023: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1023-rebalancing-coherence.md (I hope I did't miss any updates. Rust really needs a formal language definition in a single document that is kept current with releases.)

Comment: @starblue I'm unclear as to why you are bringing up coherence here. It's perfectly coherent for a crate to produce a range that is iterable, but the key trait is unstable.

Comment: I wanted to check why the `chrono` crate can't implement the `Iterator` trait for the standard range type constructors. After all the newly defined date type `NaiveDate` appears, but below the `Range` type constructor. But indeed, if you apply the formal rule that is not sufficient to allow it. I put the link because it is remarkably hard to find the RFC via search, as there is a maze of discussions about modifying the orphan rule to allow more.

Comment: @starblue I see. Yes, the standard library [implements `Iterator for Range<A: Step>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-Iterator), so a crate may not definine `Iterator` for `Range<NaiveDate>`. However, it can implement `Step` for `NaiveDate`, except that `Step` is unstable.